# How to create schema for Spark SQL for Array of struct?

Tags: json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hivecontext

How to create a schema for the below json to read schema. I am using hiveContext.read.schema().json("input.json"), and I want to ignore the first two "ErrorMessage" and "IsError" read only Report.
Below is the JSON:

```
 {  
  "ErrorMessage": null,
  "IsError": false,
   "Report":{  
      "tl":[  
         {  
            "TlID":"F6",
            "CID":"mo"
         },
         {  
            "TlID":"Fk",
            "CID":"mo"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I created the below schema :

```
val schema = StructType(
            Array(
                   StructField("Report", StructType(
                     Array(
                                                     StructField
                                                     ("tl",ArrayType(StructType(Array(
                                                                    StructField("TlID", StringType),
                                                                    StructField("CID", IntegerType)
                                                                  )))))))))

Below is my json.printSchema() :
root
 |-- Report: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- tl: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- TlID: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- CID: integer (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The schema is incorrect. `CID` in your data is clearly not `String` (`"mo"`). Use

```
val schema = StructType(Array(
  StructField("Report", StructType(
    Array(
        StructField
        ("tl",ArrayType(StructType(Array(
                       StructField("CID", StringType),
                       StructField("TlID", StringType)
                          )))))))))
```

and:

```
val df = Seq("""{  
  "ErrorMessage": null,
  "IsError": false,
   "Report":{  
      "tl":[  
         {  
            "TlID":"F6",
            "CID":"mo"
         },
         {  
            "TlID":"Fk",
            "CID":"mo"
         }
      ]
   }
}""").toDS

spark.read.schema(schema).json(df).show(false)
+--------------------------------+
|Report                          |
+--------------------------------+
|[WrappedArray([mo,F6], [mo,Fk])]| 
+--------------------------------+
```

Comment: I changed the CID to StringType, but when I do show(), it is returning "null"

Answer (score -1):

```
Datatype: array<struct<metrics_name:string,metrics_value:string>>


  import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{ArrayType}

  StructField("usage_metrics", ArrayType(StructType(
    Array(
      StructField("metric_name", StringType, true),
      StructField("metric_value", StringType, true)
    )
  ))))
```